# Temperature Converter Issue

Tags: python, function, if-statement, tkinter

I am making a temperature converter for my first main project using a GUI, namely the Tkinter module. I do not have any problems with initializing the GUI. That works fine (to my knowledge). I need some assistance with making the IF statements to call each function related to the conversion. The problem I am having with that is I am not sure how to show equivalence between two items from two different lists. Here is my code (I know that I am missing some things. Obviously the if statements.)

```
from tkinter import *

gui = Tk()
gui.title(string='Temperature Converter')
#create the GUI
fromUnit = StringVar()
#variable which holds the value of which unit is active in "units1"
toUnit = StringVar()
#variable which holds the value of which unit is active in "units2"
initialTemp = StringVar()
#the initial temperature entered in "enterTemp" entry
initialTemp.set('0')
#set the initial temperature to 0
convertedTemp = StringVar()
#used to display the converted temperature through "displayTemp" 
convertedTemp.set('0')
#set the converted temperature to 0

units1 = ('Celsius', 'Fahrenheit', 'Kelvin') #the units used in the OptionMenu
units2 = ('Celsius', 'Fahrenheit', 'Kelvin')

fromUnit.set(units1[0]) #set the active element to the item in index[0] of units1
toUnit.set(units2[0]) #set the active element to the item in index[0] of units2

# celsius-celcius conversion
def celsius_to_celsius():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

# celsius-kelvin conversion
def celsius_to_kelvin():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = (currentTemp + 273.15)
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

# celsius-fahrenheit conversion
def celsius_to_fahrenheit():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = (currentTemp * (9/5))+32
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

#fahrenheit-fahrenheit conversion
def fahrenheit_to_fahrenheit():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

#fahrenheit-celsius conversion
def fahrenheit_to_celsius():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = ((currentTemp - 32)*(5/9))
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

#fahrenheit-kelvin conversion
def fahrenheit_to_kelvin():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = ((currentTemp - 32)*(5/9)+273.15)
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

#kelvin-kelvin conversion
def kelvin_to_kelvin():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

#kelvin-celsius conversion
def kelvin_to_celsius():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = (currentTemp - 273.15)
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

#kelvin-fahrenheit conversion
def kelvin_to_fahrenheit():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = (((currentTemp - 273.15)*(9/5))+32)
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

#main function
#contains the if statements which select which conversion to use
def convert_Temp():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    if (fromUnit, toUnit) == ('Celsius','Celsius'):
        celsius_to_celsius()


gui.geometry('+100+100')
#set up the geometry

enterTemp = Entry(gui,textvariable=initialTemp,justify=RIGHT)
enterTemp.grid(row=0,column=0)
#Entry which receives the temperature to convert

convertFromUnit = OptionMenu(gui,fromUnit,*units1)
convertFromUnit.grid(row=0,column=1)
#Option Menu which selects which unit to convert from

displayTemp = Label(gui,textvariable=convertedTemp)
displayTemp.grid(row=1,column=0)
#Label which displays the temperature
#Takes text variable "convertTemp"

convertToUnit = OptionMenu(gui,toUnit,*units2)
convertToUnit.grid(row=1,column=1)
#Option Menu which selects which unit to convert to

convertButton = Button(gui,text='Convert',command=convert_Temp)
convertButton.grid(row=2,column=1)
#Button that starts the conversion
#Calls the main function "convert_Temp"

gui.mainloop()
#End of the main loop
```

Thanks for viewing and any help and criticism you provide. No knowledge is wasted!
Cheers

Comment: [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).  If you're saying something more than once, you're saying it too many times.  Also, this belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would have done something like this: http://codepad.org/xQ7HQ3ft (very quick and dirty, could use some improvements)

Comment: @NullUserException I attempted that previously. However, I just started programming and I am not up to par with classes and objects. As is, if you run the code, it will not change the label. But if I remove the if statement and do something simple such as just calling the function, I can get an change. However, when I add the if statements, I run into trouble. I did some quazi debugging which would create an error message if the IF statement was not true.

Comment: It immdediately threw the error message when the IF statement was executed.

Comment: You might show us what you have attempted (and raised errors) [instead/in addition] of what works...

Comment: Replacing your condition by `if (fromUnit.get(), toUnit.get()) == ('Celsius','Celsius'):` might do the job. `fromUnit` and `toUnit` are Tkinter variable an thus need to be accessed through `get()`and `set(value)`

Answer (score 1):

*As pointed in comments, you have a few architecture flaws (which is normal since you are learning) and you might have interesting feedback from [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) community (it is another site of stackexchange network).*

Here a few options you can use to perform what you called the *If statements*. The fact you
have already wrapped conversion in functions broadens possibilities.

1) enumerate all combination in if

What you have started, with a difference: use `fromUnit.get()` to access the value of a tkinter variable<sup>1</sup>.

```
if (fromUnit.get(), toUnit.get()) == ('Celsius','Celsius'):
    celsius_to_celsius()
if (fromUnit.get(), toUnit.get()) == ('Celsius','Fahrenheit'):
    celsius_to_fahrenheit()
if (fromUnit.get(), toUnit.get()) == ('Celsius','Kelvin'):
    celsius_to_kelvin()
```

2) nested if

```
if fromUnit.get() == 'Celsius':
    if toUnit.get()) == 'Celsius':
        celsius_to_celsius()
    if toUnit.get()) == 'Fahrenheit':
        celsius_to_fahrenheit()
    if toUnit.get()) == 'Kelvin':
        celsius_to_kelvin()
```

3) use a dictionary (associative arrray) to store functions

```
converters = {
    'Celsius' : {
        'Celsius' : celsius_to_celsius,
        'Fahrenheit': celsius_to_fahrenheit,
        'Kelvin': celsius_to_kelvin},
    'Fahrenheit' : {
        'Celsius' : fahrenheit_to_celsius,
        'Fahrenheit': fahrenheit_to_fahrenheit,
        'Kelvin': fahrenheit_to_kelvin},
    #...
}
#retrieve function, and call it (through the () at the end)
converters [fromUnit.get()] [toUnit.get()] ()
```

In fact, it uses nested dictionary. You can also use only one dictionary

```
converters = {
    ('Celsius', 'Celsius') : celsius_to_celsius,
    ('Celsius', 'Fahrenheit'): celsius_to_fahrenheit,
    ('Celsius', 'Kelvin'): celsius_to_kelvin,
}
converters [(fromUnit.get(), toUnit.get())] ()
```

4) The consistent naming scheme you use allow to generate function name

```
function_name = fromUnit.get().lower() + "_to_" + toUnit.get().lower()
globals()[function_name] ()
```

5) Delegate the dispatch

Often, big combinatory if (or switches in languages where it exist) are an appeal to refactoring.
For instance, you might perfom preliminary work on `convertFromUnit` or `fromUnit` (respectively `*toUnit`).

The mechanism using nested dictionary is pretty close to what is used inside Python object.

```
def fromUnitCallback():
    global _converter
    _converter = globals()[fromUnit.get()]()

def toUnitCallback():
    global _function_name
    _function_name = toUnit.get().lower()

def convert_Temp():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    _converter.set(currentTemp)
    converted = getattr(_converter, _function_name) ()
    convertedTemp.set(converted)

class Kelvin:
    def __init__(self, val=0):
        self.__kelvin = val

    def kelvin(self):
        return self.__kelvin

    def celsius(self):
        return self.__kelvin - 273.15

    def fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.__kelvin - 273.15)*1.8 + 32

    def set(self, val):
        self.__kelvin = val

class Celsius(Kelvin):
    def __init__(self, val):
        Kelvin.__init__(self)
        self.set(val)

    def set(self, val):
        Kelvin.set(self, val + 273.15)

class Fahrenheit:
    def __init__(self, val):
        Kelvin.__init__(self)
        self.set(val)

    def set(self, val):
        Kelvin.set((val - 32)*5/9 + 273.15)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Tkinter variable are objects, that is compound artefact embeding values and related method. The serve the same purpose of regular variable, except they can be `traced`, that is be warned that their value changed. They are used in combination with tkinter widgets to ease manipulation. Here, you want to compare the content of `fromUnit` with literal string `'Celsius'`, thus you have to ask `fromUnit` the string through `get` method. For more details, see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. I eventually found out on my own that the key problem I was having was that I needed to call the '.get()' method. I found a way to test for it by instead of calling a function to print the converted temperature, changing the value of the Label to what the "Unit" was. When it did not return a value, I realized what I did wrong. Then I tweaked the code to be a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final source code from the program I started above.

```
from tkinter import *

gui = Tk()
gui.title(string='Temperature Converter')
#create the GUI
fromUnit = StringVar()
#variable which holds the value of which unit is active in "units1"
toUnit = StringVar()
#variable which holds the value of which unit is active in "units2"
initialTemp = StringVar()
#set the initial temperature to 0
convertedTemp = StringVar()
#used to display the converted temperature through "displayTemp" 
convertedTemp.set('0')
#set the converted temperature to 0

units1 = ('Celsius', 'Fahrenheit', 'Kelvin') #the units used in the OptionMenu
units2 = ('Celsius', 'Fahrenheit', 'Kelvin')

fromUnit.set(units1[0]) #set the active element to the item in index[0] of units1
toUnit.set(units2[0]) #set the active element to the item in index[0] of units2

#main function
#contains the if statements which select which conversion to use
def convert_Temp():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    cu1 = fromUnit.get()
    cu2 = toUnit.get()

    if (cu1, cu2) == ('Celsius', 'Celsius'):
        c_c()
    elif (cu1, cu2) == ('Celsius', 'Kelvin'):
        c_k()
    elif (cu1, cu2) == ('Celsius', 'Fahrenheit'):
        c_f()
    elif (cu1, cu2) == ('Fahrenheit', 'Fahrenheit'):
        f_f()
    elif (cu1, cu2) == ('Fahrenheit', 'Celsius'):
        f_c()
    elif (cu1, cu2) == ('Fahrenheit', 'Kelvin'):
        f_k()
    elif (cu1, cu2) == ('Kelvin', 'Kelvin'):
        k_k()
    elif (cu1, cu2) == ('Kelvin', 'Celsius'):
        k_c()
    elif (cu1, cu2) == ('Kelvin', 'Fahrenheit'):
        k_f()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(title='ERROR', message='Error in the IF statements')

# celsius-celcius conversion
def c_c():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = round(currentTemp, 2)
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

# celsius-kelvin conversion
def c_k():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = (currentTemp + 273.15)
    currentTemp = round(currentTemp, 2)
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

# celsius-fahrenheit conversion
def c_f():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = (currentTemp * (9/5))+32
    currentTemp = round(currentTemp, 2)
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

#fahrenheit-fahrenheit conversion
def f_f():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = round(currentTemp, 2)
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

#fahrenheit-celsius conversion
def f_c():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = (currentTemp - 32)*(5/9)
    currentTemp = round(currentTemp, 2)
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

#fahrenheit-kelvin conversion
def f_k():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = ((currentTemp - 32)*(5/9)+273.15)
    currentTemp = round(currentTemp, 2)
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

#kelvin-kelvin conversion
def k_k():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = round(currentTemp, 2)
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

#kelvin-celsius conversion
def k_c():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = (currentTemp - 273.15)
    currentTemp = round(currentTemp, 2)
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)

#kelvin-fahrenheit conversion
def k_f():
    currentTemp = float(initialTemp.get())
    currentTemp = (((currentTemp - 273.15)*(9/5))+32)
    currentTemp = round(currentTemp, 2)
    convertedTemp.set(currentTemp)


gui.geometry('+100+100')
#set up the geometry

enterTemp = Entry(gui,textvariable=initialTemp,justify=RIGHT)
enterTemp.grid(row=0,column=0)
#Entry which receives the temperature to convert

convertFromUnit = OptionMenu(gui,fromUnit,*units1)
convertFromUnit.grid(row=0,column=1)
#Option Menu which selects which unit to convert from

displayTemp = Label(gui,textvariable=convertedTemp)
displayTemp.grid(row=1,column=0)
#Label which displays the temperature
#Takes text variable "convertTemp"

convertToUnit = OptionMenu(gui,toUnit,*units2)
convertToUnit.grid(row=1,column=1)
#Option Menu which selects which unit to convert to

convertButton = Button(gui,text='Convert',command=convert_Temp)
convertButton.grid(row=2,column=1)
#Button that starts the conversion
#Calls the main function "convert_Temp"

gui.mainloop()
#End of the main loop
```

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow! It is a Question&Answer site (more than a forum), thus we try to keep questions and answer as generic and so avoid greetings in the body of question and answers. The common way to thanks people is to upvote (comments, answers) or accept an answer. You might give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/about and http://stackoverflow.com/faq.